# How to create custom event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi
I'd like to describe a scenario I'd like to accomplish, and I have no idea how to

I'd like to bind\live on an element to a custom 'myclick':

```
$('#somediv').bind('myclick', function() {});
```

obviously, I'd like to trigger this event only when something happens to that element, 
e.g. if myclick has occurred on that element

I know how to trigger a custom event on a specific element (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Clarifications to the question:
I will define what does myclick mean (e.g. 3 clicks in a row on that element)
how can I tell when it happened on 'somediv' ?
Do I somehow register via jquery to elements that did bind\live on them? if so, how?

a complete example is:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script to include jquery>
   <script to include MYCODE.js>

   <script>
     $('#somediv').bind('myclick', function() { alert('myclick'); } );
   </script>

   <body>
      <div id='somediv'></div>
   </body>
<head>
</html>
```

so my question is: what does MYCODE.js contain?
how can it tell that some custom logic that it defines, happened on 'somediv' ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Um, what's the question?

Comment: I don't see the problem here - your question describes both how to bind a custom event, and how to fire it. That's it.

Comment: @rsplak while I agree that 17% is low, not all of those questions have answers that solve the OP's problems.

Comment: @Nadav: not a big deal. The official position on this (even the extreme case where you post a question that _you already know the answer to!_): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a plugin for this - 
a good place to start is at http://blogs.sitepoint.com/how-to-develop-a-jquery-plugin/
and http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/

I've written my plugin, and placed it here if anyone is interested.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-touch-area/

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

`.trigger()` is the method you are looking for. It must be called on the same DOM element that you used in `.bind()`

```
$('#somediv').trigger('myclick')
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Jeff says, you need to call `$('#somediv').trigger('myclick');` in any logic that should cause the event to fire. Your binding example in your original question looks right to me, so that should be all you need to do.